# UITableView as cell on another UITableView cancel the scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, coverflow

I have a UITableView that their cells are UITableViews (the root tableView is [rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384701/resize-cells-when-rotating-uitableview) to work in landscape, similar to the CoverFlow).

The tableview cells show fine, but I can't scroll it, I think because the root tableView capture all the touch events.

The horizontal tableview can show dozens of cell tableviews, so I need to preserve the ability to swipe left/right the root tableview but scroll down/up the cells tableviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally put a UIScrollView instead of a UITableView. Everything work fine now:

```
self.floatingColumns = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
self.floatingColumns.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self.floatingColumns setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.floatingColumns setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this similar to what the Pulse app does? If the table view doesn't automatically handle this for you, you may have to subclass UITableView and implement your own gesture responders. Shouldn't be too difficult though—just handle flicks and drags. You could also try enabling/disabling user interaction on one of the table views based on user scroll/flick direction.

Comment: Having not experience with control dev on coccoa touch, exist a sample un how do that? Is similar to UITableView on ScrollView?

Comment: Try Apple's Touches sample code:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like Pulse, this tutorial might help:
http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/creating-pulse-style-scrolling-horizontally-scrolling-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uitableviewcell/

It shows how to add horizontally scrolling tableviews to tableview cells. Pretty cool!

Comment: Good link, but I'm interested in the reorder of the cells, not in the display of the home.

Comment: Then you'd be better off using scrollviews, which as i see you've already done.